# Calling asp.net OnClick method from jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

When an anchor tag is clicked, I want to call asp code behind function.

```
$(".abc").unbind().bind("click", function (ev) {
$("#suppLog").click();


<asp:Button ID = "suppLog" runat = "server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="suppLog_Click" style = "display: none" />
```

But this is not calling it. So I tried changing to normal js as follows -

```
document.getElementById('<%= suppLog.ClientID %>').click();
```

This too did not work and following error came - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of property 'click': object is null or undefined

I checked by alert(document.getElementById('<%= suppLog.ClientID %>'));
And it came as null.

How to resolve this please?

Comment: Try: `document.getElementById('suppLog').click();`

Comment: What does `alert('<%= suppLog.ClientID %>')` ? Also - do u need `ClientIDMode="Static"` - what happens if u remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally prefer not to mix asp generated IDs at all, and instead wrap my server controls in markup and query on that:

```
$(".abc").unbind().bind("click", function (ev) {
  $("#supLogContainer input").click();
  return false;
}

<div id="supLogContainer">
<asp:Button ID = "suppLog" runat = "server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="suppLog_Click" style = "display: none" />
</div>
```

**Be sure to return false in the other item's click function**, or the page will post back before it has the chance to fire the second click.

Comment: ah, yes. I always forget that the element you set ".abc" to is important. If it is a button type element, you need to return false in its JS click handler or it will post the (non existent) form data back to the server and the page will reload without firing the second click.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use Jquery trigger function
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/